# Trying to create a pivot chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

For reasons that are too long to explain here I need to create a custom chart out of an existing pivot table (which already has another chart attached to it).

The number of columns in the displayed range changes depending on the slicer settings.

What happens is that if I manually delete the created chart, select the new region and recreate the chart, everything is fine.

If I do the same thing with VBA (recorded the steps) it works sometimes
(especially if I delete the chart manually before running the code) but most of the time it will create a different chart and then errors out.

Here is what happens:

I find the chart from the last run (it's always shape[3]):

```
Dim ch As Shape
Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    Set ch = ActiveSheet.Shapes(i)


' any newly created chart will be called Chart XXXX and the shape index   
' will be higher than my two initial (static shapes) on the sheet:

   If InStr(1, ch.Name, "Chart", 1) > 0 And i > 2 Then


     ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ch.Name).Activate
     ActiveChart.Parent.Delete   ' this will actually visibly always        
                                 ' delete the sheet correctly!

     'I tried this also out of desperation with the same result:
     ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
     Application.CutCopyMode = False

   End If

    Next
```

So far so good, the chart has been deleted, now I find the range in that pivot that will have a different size depending on the slicers:

```
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim lLastRow, lFirstCol, lLastCol As Long

   Set PRange = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Full Chart").TableRange2
   lLastRow = PRange(PRange.Rows.Count, 1).Row
   lFirstCol = PRange.Column
   lLastCol = PRange(1, PRange.Columns.Count).Column

Dim ValueRange As Range
Dim XRange As Range
Set ValueRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lLastRow, lFirstCol + 1), Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol - 1))
Set XRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lLastRow - 1, lFirstCol + 1), Cells(lLastRow - 1, lLastCol - 1))
```

At this time I have all I need and can create the Chart:
(I tested that the ranges are correct, and when the code works it does show the correct values indeed.)

```
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlColumnClustered).Select
    '*****
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries  
    'xxxxx
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='Year over year'!$AE$5"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = ValueRange
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = XRange
```

What happens is that at **** sometimes a duplicate of my existing chart is created instead of an empty container (that's why I try the delete the clipboard there)
which causes the code to crash at xxxx because the ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1) already exists.

It's just weird that it does not happen consistently.

I think the

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlColumnClustered).Select
```

is the culprit, why would it insert a complete chart with data?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning directly to a variable and working with that.

```
Dim myChart as Shape
Set myChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlColumnClustered) 'even better to explicitly declare worksheet

With myChart
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries  
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='Year over year'!$AE$5"
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = ValueRange
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = XRange
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much.   I might try it sometime as I have found another way to get what I wanted to show. Maybe your answer will help another confused user.